# Swift subscript with generic data type

Tags: swift, generics, types, subscript

I am trying to program a two-dimensional data storage struct for various data types. However, I am struggling with the subscript for setting the data due 'Cannot assign value of type 'T' to subscript of type 'T' errors. Any help is much appreciated!

```
struct dataMatrix<T> : Sequence, IteratorProtocol {
    var rows: Int, columns: Int
    var data: [T]
    var position = 0
    
    init(rows: Int, columns: Int) {
        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns
        data = Array<T>()
    }
    
    func valueAt(column: Int, row: Int) -> T? {
        guard column >= 0 && row >= 0 && column < columns else {
                return nil
            }

        let indexcolumn = column + row * columns

            guard indexcolumn < data.count else {
                return nil
            }

            return data[indexcolumn]
        }
    }
    
    subscript<T>(column: Int, row:Int) -> T?{
        get{
            return valueAt(column: column, row: row) as? T
        }
        set{
            data[(column * row) + column] = (newValue as! T) // does not compile
        }   
    }
    
    // sequence iterator protorocl methods
    mutating func next() -> String? {
        if position <= data.count{
            print(position)
            defer { position += 1 }
            return "\(position)"
        }else{
            defer {position = 0}
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Side notes: Types should use camel case (`DataMatrix`). There is an extra closing curly bracket after `valueAt` in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
subscript<T>(column: Int, row:Int) -> T?{
```

defines a generic method with a type placeholder `T` which is unrelated to the generic type `T` of `struct dataMatrix<T>`. The solution is simple: Remove the type placeholder:

```
subscript(column: Int, row: Int) -> T? {
    // ...
}
```

That makes also the type casts inside the getter and setter unnecessary. You only have to decide what to do if the setter is called with a `nil` argument (e.g.: nothing):

```
subscript(column: Int, row: Int) -> T? {
    get {
        return valueAt(column: column, row: row)
    }
    set {
        if let value = newValue {
            data[(column * row) + column] = value
        }
    }
}
```

Another option is to make the return type of the subscript method non-optional, and treat invalid indices as a fatal error (which is how the Swift `Array` handles it):

```
subscript(column: Int, row: Int) -> T {
    get {
        guard let value = valueAt(column: column, row: row) else {
            fatalError("index out of bounds")
        }
        return value
    }
    set {
        data[(column * row) + column] = newValue
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Martin that makes sense. I am still getting the EXC_BREAKPOINT errors when calling the setter on a fresh instance. I assume it is because I am not initializing the data array properly, i.e. without placeholder data. Is there a way of initiating the data array with the appropriate number of nils, or with the placeholder  instances of the respective  <T> type to not get out of bound errors? Thanks!

Comment: @nonresidentalien: Indeed (although that is a different problem). You have to initialize the array with proper number of elements, something like `data = Array<T>(repeating: XXX, count: rows * columns)` where `XXX` is a “default element”. You might need to pass the default element as an additional argument to the init function.